# jQuery how to delete or hide all html except selected <div>

Tags: jquery

Given the following markup:

```
<div class=foo>
  <!-- comments -->
  some junk content
  <input type=button value=click />
  <div class=bar>
    good content
  </div>
  more junk content
  <div class=bar>
    more good content
  </div>
  even more junk
</div>
```

I need to remove everything except the bar divs, so I would end up with only:

```
  <div class=bar>
    good content
  </div>
  <div class=bar>
    more good content
  </div>
```

I have tried: `$('.foo :not(.bar)').hide();` but elements that don't meet this selection are obviously remaining.

Is there a selector that will match *everything*, or should I extract the bar divs to a new var?

Comment: not totally sure of api calls but something like $(".foo").filter(".bar").hide() might work.  Not sure if that selects text nodes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$(function(){
    var html = [];
    $('.bar').each(function(i, item) { html.push($(this).html()); });
    $('.foo').html('<div class="bar">' + html.join('</div><div class="bar">') + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to wrap the content inside the `.foo` element, between the `.bar` elements in seperate elements. Otherwise, you will have no hide these bastards without hiding the entire `.foo` element.

```
<div class=foo>
  <!-- comments -->
  <div>some junk content</div>
  <input type=button value=click />
  <div class=bar>
    good content
  </div>
  <div>more junk content</div>
  <div class=bar>
    more good content
  </div>
  <div>even more junk</div>
</div>
```

With such wrappers in place, your should be able to do something like this:

```
$(".foo > *:not(.bar)").hide();
```

Or, if you do not care about being able to undo:

```
$(".foo > *:not(.bar)").remove();
```