# Clear all html controls except some

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which is consist of Textbox, Textarea, Password and some of the kendo dropdown and combobox. I want to clear all the controls on `Clear` button click except one textbox and textarea.

I have done following for clearing all controls.

```
$('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('form').find('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]').val('');
});
```

I don't know how not to clear some of the controls.

Comment: post your html & specify which you don't want to clear

Comment: Have you tried .not('yadayada

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: use .not() like `$(this).closest('form').find('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]').not('<selector>').val('');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality by following method:

Apply some class to controls which you don't want to clear like below:

```
<div id="parent"> 
    <input type="text" id="textOne" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="textTwo" class="ignoreT" /><br/>
    <textarea id="textThree" class="ignoreTA" ></textarea><br/>
    <input type="text" id="textFour" class="ignoreT" /><br/>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Now write following code to clear all controls except ignore class controls:

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('input:not(".ignoreT"), textarea:not("ignoreTA")').val('');
});
```

or you can apply same class(suppose ignore) to all controls and write following code:

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('form').find('input, textarea').not('.ignore').val('');
});
```

See if it works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks it's works for me , and also thanks for Good Explanation with proper Example

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) filtering method:

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
$('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form')
           .find('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]')
           .not('foo')
           .val('');
});
```

Where `foo` is a selector referring to the exceptions (i.e. controls you *don't* want to clear).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use **[:not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** like,

Let `someId` is a textbox and `otherId` is that texxarea which should not be empty

```
$('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input:not(#someId),textarea:not(#otherId)').val('');
});
```

Also you can use a common class like `non-empty-elements` with `:not` like

```
$('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form')
           .find('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]')
           .not('.non-empty-elements')// filter non-empty-elements
           .val('');
});
```

Note that, you need to add `non-empty-elements` class to those elements which should not be empty

Answer (score 1):

use [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]').not('#myControlId1,#myControlId2').val('');
```

where `#myControlId1` & `#myControlId1` are the IDs of controls  which you don't want to clear

Answer (score 0):

you can use [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp) and define with except one like

```
$(html).not('span:first').remove();
```

Refer link:
1. [jquery remove all elements except for first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874298/jquery-remove-all-elements-except-for-first-one)

2 [How to remove all the <tr> from a table except the first one using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582173/how-to-remove-all-the-tr-from-a-table-except-the-first-one-using-jquery)

Based on css:- [jQuery how to delete or hide all html except selected <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168645/jquery-how-to-delete-or-hide-all-html-except-selected-div)